# Comparing varchar date with sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date, sysdate

I am trying to query `sum_date WHERE sum_date BETWEEN (sysdate-1) AND (sysdate-30)`

In my `SELECT` statement I have tried `TO_DATE(sum_date, 'DD-MM-YY')` and `sysdate`

But it throws error:

> `"literal does not match format string."`

- `Sum_date` is stored as `varchar20` and looks like `2014-01-07`.
- `sysdate` looks like `18-SEP-14`.

Comment: Try this TO_DATE(sum_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')

Answer (score 3):

Your format is `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, so:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  TO_DATE(sum_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
       BETWEEN (sysdate - 30) AND (sysdate - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of your session to match your need:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

create table y 
  ( y varchar2(10));  
  select y.*, rowid from y
;

select * from y where y between sysdate -10000 and sysdate +100000;
select * from y where to_date(y,'YYYY-MM-DD') between '2010-04-01' and '2016-04-01' ;
```